# Recursive algorithm to establish level of pairs element or to find the master element

Tags: java, recursion

I am having a hard time trying to solve the next problem. I have a List of object (in java) which stores data in fields like:

```
Master Dependent
100    101
101    102
105    107
111    112
110    111
```

and i need to group them based on their relationship between Master and Dependent and set them levels.
I need to find the .. pure master, which is the one never appears in Dependent field.

Desired result would be:

```
Master Dependent Level
100    101       1
101    102       2

105    107       1

110    111       1
111    112       2
```

I tryied to solve with a recursive function but i can't achieve the levels.

example function:

localitem = dependent

```
public List<TransferPolicyItem> defineConsistencyPairs(Integer pairNo, String item, List<TransferPolicyItem> transferPolicyItemList){
    for(TransferPolicyItem transferPolicyItem : transferPolicyItemList) {
        if (item.equals(transferPolicyItem.getLocalItem().getId())
                && !transferPolicyItem.getConsistencyChecked()
                && transferPolicyItem.getMasterItemId() != null) {

            transferPolicyItem.setConsistencyChecked(true);
            transferPolicyItem.setConsistencyPair(pairNo);
            defineConsistencyPairs(pairNo, transferPolicyItem.getMasterItemId(), transferPolicyItemList);

        } else if (item.equals(transferPolicyItem.getMasterItemId())
                && !transferPolicyItem.getConsistencyChecked()) {

            transferPolicyItem.setConsistencyChecked(true);
            transferPolicyItem.setConsistencyPair(pairNo);
            defineConsistencyPairs(pairNo, transferPolicyItem.getLocalItem().getId(), transferPolicyItemList);
        }
    }
    return transferPolicyItemList;
}
```

Comment: Mind to share your function?

Comment: @elPolloLoco hey, i just edited the original post.

Comment: `pure master, which is the one never appears in Dependent field`  is there only one (meaning that all other values have master) ?  Can a value have more than one master ?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a terribly technique for solving this problem.
Also, master - dependent is not the best way to think of these values.
Instead, think of them as parent - child and think of your level as generation.
Recognize that a parent in one row can be a child in a previous row.
Here is a non-recursive solution:

1. Sort the input by parent id.
   This resolves the problem of (111, 112) appearing in the data stream before (110, 111).
2. Run through the input data and create a 2nd collection that tracks generation for a given id.
   Child generation is parent generation +1 (start parent generation at 0).
3. Run through the input data and assign a generation to the (parent, child) relationship (the child's generation level).

Here are the steps:

```
Initial Input
Parent  Child
100     101
101     102
105     107
111     112
110     111

Sort the input:
Parent  Child
100     101
101     102
105     107
110     111
111     112

Assign generation:
Value  Generation
100    0
101    1
102    2
105    0
107    1
110    0
111    1
112    2

Assign Generation to the relationship:
Parent  Child  Generation
100     101    1
101     102    2
105     107    1
110     111    1
111     112    2
```

Comment: I am not confident that sorting resolves any problem. Is there a domain-related reason that would make A < B imply B cannot be A's parent?

Comment: How many iterations on the data-set would your answer require? I count at least 1 per level, which would be ruinous in the case of deep nesting. My answer would require O(N) recursive calls, yours is O(N^2) worst-case. Recursion is great for hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to place all pairs in a map, locate the root (the node without a parent) and then use recursion (which is actually fine: it may be slightly slower than iteration, but it I certainly find it more readable) to assign levels.

In java-flavored pseudo-code:

```
parents = new Map<Integer, Integer>()
children = new Map<Integer, Integer>()
for each pair A, B,
   children.put(A, B) 
   parents.put(B, A) 

parents.removeAll(children); // single result is the root
root = parents.iterator().next(); 

levels = new Map<Integer, Integer>()
levels.put(root, 0);
assignLevels(root, children, levels)
```

with

```
assignLevels(node, children, levels):
   level = levels.get(node) + 1
   for each child C:
       levels.put(C, level)
       assignLevevels(C, children, levels) // recursion
```